# What is the largest possible value of $E[X] - (E[X^{-1}])^{-1}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, optimization, expected-value

> Suppose $X$ is a random variable on $[A; B]$ ($0 < A < B$). What is the largest possible value of $E[X] - (E[X^{-1}])^{-1}$?

On one side it is rather obvious, that $E[X] - (E[X^{-1}])^{-1} \leq E[X] \leq B$. But this bound is clearly not tight.

On the other side, the largest value for which I managed to build example for is $(\sqrt{B} - \sqrt{A})^2$. It is the random value $X$ with following distribution:

$$P(X = A) = \frac{\sqrt{A}}{\sqrt{A} + \sqrt{B}}$$

$$P(X = B) = \frac{\sqrt{B}}{\sqrt{A} + \sqrt{B}}$$

I suspect that this lower bound is tight, but do not know how to prove it.

Comment: So, does my answer suit your need then?

Comment: @ParesseuzNguyen, not yet. However it will, if you prove that the bound is tight.

Comment: I consider this to be a fun challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the demonstration for the tight bound $( \sqrt{A}-\sqrt{B})^2$

**Demonstration**
Given our bound on $X$, we have the following inequality:
$$ \mathbb{E}( (X-A)( \frac{1}{B}-\dfrac{1}{X})) \ge 0 $$
Which gives us $ A+B -\mathbb{E}(X) \ge AB\mathbb{E}( \frac{1}{X})$, so the left hand side of our expression is :
$$ LHS \le \mathbb{E}(X) - \dfrac{AB}{ A+B-\mathbb{E}(X) }= A+B- \left[\left(A+B- \mathbb{E}(X)\right)+ \dfrac{AB}{ A+B-\mathbb{E}(X) } \right] \le A+B-2\sqrt{AB}  $$

$\square$

Answer (score 0):

A loose application of Kantorovich's would give an upper bound of
$$  LHS \le \frac{ (A-B)^2}{4A}$$

Some manipulation can be used to have better estimation but I think that this bound is already ok.